# Why does a negative SByte number have 16 bits in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, binary, bit, signed

I asked a question earlier about comparing numbers using the "And" comparison operator in If Statements and now I have been toying around with getting my head wrapped around bitwise operators. So I have written a very basic code that will allow me to see the conversion of any decimal number in binary format.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(ConvertToBinary(-1))
End Sub

Public Function ConvertToBinary(ByVal someInteger As SByte) As String
    Dim converted As String = Convert.ToString(someInteger, 2) '.PadLeft(8, "a"c)
    Return converted
End Function
```

Notice here that I am using SByte as the paramerter - which should only contain 8 bits right? However, the message box that appears has 16 bits assigned to negative numbers. Positive numbers have the correct 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Convert.ToString` overload that takes an `SByte`, so the `SByte` is being implicitly converted to a `Short`.

Comment: I believe there is? I can see that it might convert it but Intellisense says there is an Sbyte parameter for the ToString method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131015.aspx

Comment: @Adam This is a completely different overload, which requires an `IFormatProvider` as its second argument, not an integral base.