# Shifting and negating sBytes producing different type promotions

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I have my sbyte (41) which is 101001 in binary then I shift It twice to the left and It becomes -92 which is 1111111110100100 in binary meaning that It becomes a short.

But I know that whenever a positive sbyte is negated, It is promoted to Int which is demonstrated in the last 3 lines below. the 92 becomes 11111111111111111111111110100100 in binary when negated.

could you please tell me why didn't the 41 become an int too when It was shifted to the left?

```
    sbyte ehfveriuvhie1 = 41;
    Console.WriteLine(ehfveriuvhie1 + "\n" + Convert.ToString(ehfveriuvhie1, 2));
    ehfveriuvhie1 <<= 2;
    Console.WriteLine(ehfveriuvhie1 + "\n" + Convert.ToString(ehfveriuvhie1, 2));
    sbyte wrgwaefjvbh= 92;
    Console.WriteLine(-wrgwaefjvbh + "\n" + Convert.ToString(-wrgwaefjvbh, 2));
    Console.WriteLine(wrgwaefjvbh + "\n" + Convert.ToString(wrgwaefjvbh, 2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only shifted it to the left, it would have become an int.  That's written `ehfveriuvhie1 << 2`.

But you have used `<<=` which means "shift and then store it back into the original variable", and that variable is type `sbyte`, which is why the final result is `sbyte` once again.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, but how is It still an sbyte If It has 16 bits 1111111110100100 ?

Comment: Should I consider the answer here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654002/why-does-a-negative-sbyte-number-have-16-bits-in-vb-net

Comment: @EricMovsessian: An `sbyte` doesn't have 16 bits.  Maybe the output of `Convert.ToString()` has 16 characters, but that would mean it doesn't match the number of bits in its input.  Note that there is single-parameter `ToString(SByte value)`, but no two-parameter `ToString(SByte value, int base)`.  So it's matching the `ToString(Int16 value, int base)` overload

Comment: I Think I understand what you mean. I just needed to use the ToString(Int16 value, int base) to get the binary but I guess I should do It manually like this . https://dotnetfiddle.net/ln1EDN

Comment: I don't know why you would want to write that loop, especially the magic number is ugly.  You can force promotion of a value like `Convert.ToString(+ehfveriuvhie1, 2)` now it will call the `int` overload just like negation does.

Comment: I was doing that to get the binary. I know It is kind of silly.